# How to create a SetTimeout for a message alert component in Vue 3 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am getting started with Vue. I am struggling to create a SetTimeout for a message alert component.

My component looks like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "Message",
    props: {
        msg: String
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="alert alert-success mb-2 col-span-3 text-white font-medium">{{ msg }}</div>
</template>
```

And I'm passing the message through props and trying to get the message and set a time for it to disappear from the screen as below:

```
<script setup>
const msg = 'Produto cadastrado com sucesso!'

setTimeout(() => msg = "", 3000)
</script>

<template>
    <MsgAlerts :msg="msg" v-show="msg" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `msg` should be a reactive data created with [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) function in order to respond to any assignment which should be done using `.value` :

```html
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
const msg = ref('Produto cadastrado com sucesso!')

setTimeout(() => msg.value = "", 3000)
</script>

<template>
    <MsgAlerts :msg="msg" v-show="msg" />
</template>
```